# ASP.NET MVC app cant call JS or CSS files from cshtml file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, relative-path

I have a cshtml file at the following path `/Views/Home/index.cshtml`

The js file is at the path `/Public/js/main.js`.....and I use the following code to call it:  `<script src="../../Public/js/main.js"></script>`

The css file is at the path `/Public/css.main.css`....and I use the following code to call it: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Public/css/main.css">`

For both of these calls I am getting 404 error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Well? Did you make sure that in the published app the files are in the correct location? If you try to access them via URL, do you see their contents?

Comment: Its not published I am debugging using visual studio

Comment: Sure - but you can still attempt to hit the URL directly in the browser. Like Kevin's answer says, the directory your view is in has no actual bearing, and shouldn't be used in determining a relative path. What matters is the path you actually use to reach the webpage, and from there what is the relative path to the files you need.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the index is in the view folder, it renders to the root. The view folder is a server side application folder. Try taking off the `../../`. Also in your example, you css folder has a '.' after it versus a '/'.

Comment: Try just "/Public/js/main.js". Your public folder is probably on the same level as you index page.

Answer (score 0):

This article solved it for me
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1

I needed to change folder name from 'Public' to 'wwwroot'...then reference js file as follows:  `"~/js/main.js"`.  The ~ character represents the folder 'wwwroot'